# Is it Rank$(A^{T}A)$= Rank$(AA^{T})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know rank AB is not same as rank BA.

I take here particular case.  Is this particular case true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, provided we're in the real case. First off, rank is invariant under transposition i.e. $\text{rank}\ B=\text{rank}\ (B^T).$ One can show that \begin{align*}\text{rank}\ A&=\text{rank}\ (A^TA)\\
\text{rank}\ A^T&=\text{rank}\  (AA^T).
\end{align*} Since $\text{rank}\ A=\text{rank}\  A^T,$ we get that $$\text{rank}\  (A^TA)=\text{rank}\  (AA^T)$$ You can find proofs of the basic facts that I've used all over this site, although I'd suggest for you to try to show them yourself before looking.

Comment: But note that it's only true for real matrices!

Comment: Of course, which is why I used transpose, instead of Hermitian adjoint.

Comment: But you could use the transpose on a complex matrix and then the equality wouldn't hold, for example $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & i \\ 0 &0  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ i &0  \end{bmatrix}$; I think it *would* work for complex matrices when you use the conjugate transpose/Hermitian adjoint.

Comment: Sure, but typically one uses the standard transpose when talking about real matrices and the conjugate transpose for complex matrices.

Comment: @mathphys Okay, I've edited because apparently that's worthy of a down vote from somone.

Comment: @cmk Ok I'll +1 (though the -1 wasn't from me)

Comment: The downvote was mine. I cast it because I didn't understand how you got $rank(A^TA)=rank(AA^T)$ from the identity $rank(B)=rank(B^T)$. The transpose of $A^TA$ is $A^TA$ itself, not $AA^T$. Did I miss something?

Comment: @user1551 That's actually fair. I actually edited my post a little bit ago to explain that further. What you can show, without too much effort, is that the rank of $A$ is the same as $A^TA$, and that the rank of $A^T$ is the rank as $AA^T$. Now, we use the identity for $A$ and $A^T$.

Comment: It makes sense now. Thanks for the explanation.